# Prestashop feature_value_lang duplicates in db

Tags: optimization, prestashop-1.7

We have Prestashop 1.7.6 and the following problem: we have a lot of feature_value_lang duplicates. They are all associated with individual products. So instead of having one feature value associated with N products we have N feature values associated with N products, so we can't really mindlessly delete them. Has anyone had this problem? To reimport the product is not an solution. They were inserted through the API which doesn't offer many options for checking if a feature value exists or not.

What we've done so far is to analyze the database for a mysql only solution but no luck. Another option would be to create a script that checks each feature value on all products and update all accordingly and, in the process, gather all soon to be useless feature values and delete them afterwards. Any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this and it works fine:

1. Deleted all feature values from PS database
2. Added all feature values independently using a PHP script
3. Added all feature values for each product using the API and checking before if the id_feature_value exists in the temp database (another script)
4. Set them to run in a cron job.

Now, the database is 3 millions rows lighter, I can use filters and the shop runs much faster.